# SSH tunnel to home network, and access router web interface

Tags: macos, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to use an ssh tunnel from a remote location to connect to my home network and access the router web interface.

I have SSH access to the home network, and I can connect to the gateway machine "Lounge". (e.g. 192.168.1.100)

What would I need to do to proxy web requests to the router (192.168.1.1) on the home network, via "Lounge", so that I can view it from the remote location?

If it makes a difference, the "Lounge" machine is running OS X.

I want an ssh / command-line only solution to this, thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`ssh` command...

```
ssh user@remotehost -L localport:host_reachable_from_remote_host:remoteport
```

So for example...

```
ssh ocodo@100.100.100.100 -L 8080:192.168.1.1:8080
```

This will create a tunnel to `192.168.1.1` port `8080` on the remote network (reachable from the machine at `100.100.100.100`), to the local port `8080`.

Viewable via `http://localhost:8080` in your browser.

If you want to avoid having `ssh` open the shell connection on the remote machine, and just leave the tunnel open, use the switch `-N` for example.

```
ssh -N ocodo@100.100.100.100 -L 8080:192.168.1.1:8080
```

Comment: The command is good, but modern routers check something that results in _403 access denied._ Perhaps it checks origin?

Comment: @Redsandro - depends on the vendor.  I just used this tunnel method to jump on my (2 yr old) home router, and there were no issues.

Comment: I made this the accepted answer, because the question is for ssh, not puTTY.

Comment: "Your request has bad syntax or is inherently impossible to satisfy."

Answer (score 11):

Download putty if you don't already have it, the format you need for this is:

```
putty -ssh username@publicip -pw password -L localport:privateip:destinationport
```

Here is what you would use to get to 192.168.1.1 remotely through SSH:

```
putty -ssh username@publicip -pw password -L 8080:192.168.1.1:80
```

You could then open up a web browser to 127.0.0.1:8080 on the computer you created the tunnel with and up would pop the router interface.

Comment: putty is cross platform, I have done this from a linux box as well as from a windows box, and I have done it through many operating systems. The operating system should not matter on the SSH server or on the client you are using to connect.

Comment: If I do that, I get redirected to the router page of my current network (Not the remote one). If I do it with every other webpage, it works. Any solution?