# SSH tunnel through two servers to access a web service on port 9091

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

what I have is a "phone-home" service running at `remote1` that connects to `LAN1` via:

```
ssh -N -R 16864:localhost:22 <myuser.on.lan1>@<lan1.ip>
```

so from the SSH terminal on `LAN1` I can easily load terminal on `remote1` doing:

```
ssh -l <myuser.on.remote1> -p 16864 localhost
```

`remote1` is running a daemon service with a web panel on port `9091` (Transmission).

So what I want is to connect to this web interface on port `9091` on `remote1`, through `LAN1` (that already have a tunnel open on port `16864`) from my local machine.

so probably this:

```
Local machine browser -> LAN1:16864 -> 22:REMOTE1:9091
```

I've been trying quite a few different SSL commands based on what I read [HERE](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html), [HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/330131/ssh-tunnel-to-home-network-and-access-router-web-interface), [HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/366258/ssh-tunnel-over-2-servers) and the original setup is based on [THIS](http://www.tunnelsup.com/raspberry-pi-phoning-home-using-a-reverse-remote-ssh-tunnel)

I've been trying stuff like this, but I'm sure I'm close but pretty lost on what to do:

```
ssh -t -L8080:localhost:5590 user@192.168.2.42 ssh -l user -p 16864 localhost -N
```

but of course, if I'm asking here it's because I'm failing miserably. Any expert to help me out on this one?

**edit:**

I don't have any diagrams but I'll explain in a different way:

I have 3 linux computers:

- `REMOTE1` always-on raspPi on remote location, which I don't have much access to network configuration
- `LAN1` always on raspPi on my local lan, where I can setup port-forwarding, fixed IP and dynamic DNS, without issues.
- my PC, which I want to be able to access web services on `REMOTE1`

`REMOTE1` is doing a "call home" to keep a SSH connection with `LAN1` via:

```
ssh -N -R 16864:localhost:22 <myuser.on.lan1>@<lan1.ip>
```

and that part is working fine. I use my local machine terminal to SSH to `LAN1`, then inside `LAN1` machine I type:

```
ssh -l <myuser.on.remote1> -p 16864 localhost
```

and I can do terminal stuff on `REMOTE1`.

Currently I only got a service on 9091 (transmission-daemon) but I'll be installing some other stuff later.

So the question, how do I tunnel from my local machine to access the web service on port `9091` on the `REMOTE1` going through the tunneled connection on `LAN1`?

in a simplistic way:

- local machine: `ssh 8888 <magic> 1684 <magic> 9091 <magic> -N`
- open the browser on type `localhost:8888/transmission/web/` and access it the transmission-daemon on `REMOTE1`

Comment: I need pictures or something.  I am not following what needs to go where.  In any case, you probably should be using `ProxyCommand ssh -W intermediate` from the local machine so that you can build a single tunnel between the far host and local host.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I edited the question with some more details. I'll certain check it out `ProxyCommand`, thanks for the tip

Comment: I guess the biggest issue I have, is that most examples, have defined hostname/IP. And on my case, I have no idea on `REMOTE1` hostname/IP, I need to simply re-use the existing permanent connection on port `16864`

Comment: and is your PC on LAN1? And do you have any port forwarding set up at the NAT router of LAN1?

Comment: Hi @barlop that's the old question, I got a new one asking how to do the same on a Chromebook. Yes, `PC` and `LAN` are both on the same local network. I have physical and root access on LAN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First set up so you can ssh from your PC "directly" to remote1:

In your .ssh/config put:

```
Host remote1
  Proxycommand ssh -q -l <myuser.on.lan1> lan1 nc -w 600 localhost 16864
```

Make sure netcat (nc command) is installed on lan1.

You should now be able to ssh from your pc with:

```
ssh <myuser.on.remote1>@remote1
```

once this works, use:

```
ssh -L8888:localhost:9091 <myuser.on.remote1>@remote1
```

and you have access to transmission on remote1:9091 via localhost:8888

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sounds like it's what I need. I'll only be able to test it later tonight thou, I'll report back.

Comment: `PERFECT!!` =] at the end I'm using transmission on the same port it opens and I can use the same technique to expand to any other service I want to run remotely. That was my final command: `ssh -L9091:localhost:9091 budius@remote -N` (-N at the end to leave the ports open and I can access through the browser)