# User transparent SSH multihop

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

What I have is the same as this question [SSH tunnel through two servers to access a web service on port 9091](https://superuser.com/questions/772551/ssh-tunnel-through-two-servers-to-access-a-web-service-on-port-9091) (mainly because I asked that question).

But the difference now is that I'm accessing it from a Chromebook which cannot use `ProxyCommand`. All it got is the base NaCl shell running in a sandboxed Chrome tab.

- This is the "shell app" that runs it: 
  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog
- This is the FAQ with complete information about it.
  https://chromium.googlesource.com/apps/libapps/+/master/nassh/doc/faq.txt

**So a review from my previous question:**

I got 3 machines:

- `remotePi` (raspberry PI, somewhere in the world)
- `localPi` (another raspberry PI, in my local network, I have full access to it, including root, no monitor, no kb, running as headless server)
- `Chromebook` (my local machine, which is a Chromebook on the same local network as `localPi`, limited but does have the SSH as per links above).

`remotePi` have a constant SSH tunnel to `localPi`, it does it by calling the following command

```
ssh -N -R 16864:localhost:22 -p 2222 <user_on_lan>@<external_lan_ip>
```

I can access `remotePi` terminal by doing

```
Chromebook> ssh <user_on_localPi>@<localPI_ip>
localPi> ssh -l <user_on_remotePi> -p 16846 localhost
```

And in `remotePi` I have a daemon service (web interface) listening on `9091`.

a "drawing" of everything:

```
                                   16864:tunnel:22   9091:service
Chromebook <--local_net--> localPi  <--internet-->  remotePi
```

**So what I need is:**

> Access the daemon service web interface in remotePi by calling on my `Chromebook` browser `127.0.0.1:9091/web/`

On my previous computer (shown on the linked question, ubuntu laptop) I was doing it by using `ProxyCommand` on my config and calling `ssh -L9091:localhost:9091 user_on_remotePi@remotePi -N`, but now I'm on a Chromebook that can't use it and I believe there must be a way to do it anyway.

So I was wondering about 2 possible solutions:

1. some very clever and long SSH command that will "replace" what the `ProxyCommand` was doing. I always see this on tutorials like that [LINK](http://www.linuxhorizon.ro/ssh-tunnel.html) but it always relies on host name, I only have the port `16864` to connect to.
2. (preferred) add some magic to the `localPi` SSH config which will make it listen on some non-standard port (say `2222`) and auto-redirect that connection to `user_on_remotePi:localhost:16864`. So then, when I call from Chromebook `ssh user_on_localPI -p 2222 localPi_ip`, then the `localPi` will redirect this to the correct user directly on remotePi.

As you can noticed I'm a bit of a network newbie, my main expertise in app development, so any help here I'll be extremely grateful.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks a bit complex for me and i'm not that  familiar with ProxyCommand, but you say you have REMOTE, LAN, PC..  So is Chromebook the PC?

Comment: Yes. Chromebook is PC. Sorry, I'll edit to clarify in the question. And ProxyCommand was only useful when I was using an Ubuntu `PC`, now with the chromebook, that's not an option.

Comment: You could call them Pi and CB  rather than calling one LAN and one PC.  Both are computers and each is behind the same LAN.

Comment: so chromebook does it have ssh.exe?  sshd.exe?

Comment: `LAN` is a raspberry PI without monitor, keyboard or mouse connected to it. So it's essentially a headless server. It's just the shell available on the CHromebook, the question includes the link to it, but I'll also add now the official FAQ with all details available about it.

Comment: so call it HeadlessPi don't call it LAN. It's not a LAN it's a computer on a LAN. So you have HeadlessPi, RemotePi, ChromeBook.  And HeadlessPi and ChromeBook are behind the same LAN.

Comment: The NAT Router at your external LAN IP presumably port forwards to an SSH server on your headless raspberry pi on some port other than port 22, what port is that? i.e. what port does the headless pi's ssh server run on?

Comment: hi @barlop, I was not sure what to call them when writing the question. Edited to Chromebook, localPi and remotePi, much clear now, good suggestion. Yes the NAT router redirects from external 2222 to localPi:22, but from my understand that is completely transparent for the setup and all necessary to complete the puzzle is the constant connection on localPI:16864

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25268/discussion-between-barlop-and-budius).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we got there in the chat

```
LocalPi>ssh -L *:5678:127.0.0.1:9091  remoteuser@127.0.0.1 -p 16864
```

then on chromebook,  `http://localpi_IP:5678`

So the remote pi had done an SSH -R creating port 16864 on the localpi.

He was already able to get a terminal to his raspberry pi, doing `localpi>ssh remoteuser@127.0.0.1 -p 16864`   We added a -L  to open port 5678 on his localpi, so he can then connect from a device e.g. chromebook, to his localpi, which goes to his remotepi which forwards to a web server on itself/his remote pi.

So there are two ssh commands in total. The one from his remote pi to his localpi. And one from his localpi to his remotepi.

We just amended the second one, the one from his localpi to his remotepi. To tunnel to a web server on his remote pi.

It is actually tunneling through a tunnel.

Comment: @Budius  What do you use to keep the connection going? For example, suppose LocalPi restarts?  And suppose RemotePi restarts?  Some might use a script that runs ssh in a loop and so tries again when the connection goes.  You mentioned -N though -N would stop the shell appearing it wouldn't keep the connection active AFAIK.

Comment: my original setup was following this: http://www.tunnelsup.com/raspberry-pi-phoning-home-using-a-reverse-remote-ssh-tunnel It's a little script that checks connection and connect if necessary in a cron job running every 3 min. So if connection drops or PI reboots, it will reconnect soon after.